# Magento 2.4 altering admin controller post value using plugin

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I tried changing the values using before dispatch plugin using below code but it's not working.

```
public function beforeExecute(\Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save $subject){
$info =  $subject->getRequest()->getParam('info', false);
$subject->getRequest()->setParam('info', 'somevalue'); return true;}
```

Where i am going wrong here?